# 10 digit allow after decimal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I am using primeface inputText and want to allow only 10 digit after decimal, plz provide how to do this using jquery.
below is my code where I want to apply

```
  <p:inputText id=inputId/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <h:inputText id="regReward" label="#{msg.registrationReward}"
        value="#{program.regReward}">
        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="1000000" />
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###0.##########" />
    </h:inputText>
```

or create `Validator` and call it like this:

```
    <h:inputText id="regReward" label="#{msg.registrationReward}"
        value="#{program.regReward}">
        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="1000000" />
        <f:validator validatorId="dec-points-validator" />
        <f:attribute name="decimalAllowed" value="#{referenceData.amountDecPlace}" />
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###0.######" />
    </h:inputText>
```