# How to set a format to in <h:inputtext> live

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<h:form>` where I inset this value `175669663` in to the `<h:inputtext>`, but I want to assign the format `##.###.###-#` or `#.###.###-#`, to unselect the `<h:inputtext>` change to `17.566.966-3`.

Comment: it's to be changed when exactly ?

Comment: What about format it in bean? If you store it as number, then you can convert it - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981851/10-digit-allow-after-decimal-using-jquery/21993026#21993026) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the primefaces inputMask component to this validation with a mask like you want.

Look some examples in this official showcase: [Primefaces Input Mask](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml)